# Filtering on non-bound user field returns zero results

Tags: acumatica

I have a customization to the 'Add Payment to Deposit' popup screen used on the 'Bank Deposits' screen.  I need to look back to get the BatNbr of the Journal Voucher record so that the payments to add can be filtered on that field.   The RowSelected event works fine and brings back the BatNbr - but as soon as you filter on that field, I always get zero results.  Filtering by this field in any way always returns zero results.

I've used what I think is the proper technique of using the PXConnectionScope - but this doesn't seem to make any difference either.  I had a former support case where this fixed the problem, but it doesn't help here.  I also tried using the PXScalar attribute (shown commented out), but that also didn't work.

Here's my code:

DAC extension for user field:

```
public class PaymentInfoExt : PXCacheExtension<PaymentInfo>
{
    #region UsrBatchNbr
    public abstract class usrBatchNbr : IBqlField { }
    [PXString(15, IsUnicode = true)]
    [PXUIField(DisplayName = "JV Batch Nbr*")]
    //[PXDBScalar(typeof(Search<GLTranDoc.batchNbr,
    //                   Where<GLTranDoc.refNbr, Equal<PaymentInfo.refNbr>,
    //                   And<GLTranDoc.tranModule, Equal<Constants.aR>>>>>))]
    public virtual string UsrBatchNbr { get; set; }
    #endregion
}
```

In the graph extension:

*Note - If I try using the RowSelecting event, I get no results.  Only the RowSelected event brings back results.

```
    public virtual void PaymentInfo_RowSelected(PXCache sender, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e)
    {
        var pi = e.Row as PaymentInfo;
        if (pi != null)
        {
            //select Refnbr from GLTranDoc where CompanyID = '' and BatchNBR = '' and TranModule = 'AR'
            using (new PXConnectionScope())
            {
                var gltd = (GLTranDoc)PXSelect<GLTranDoc,
                                  Where<GLTranDoc.refNbr, Equal<Required<GLTranDoc.refNbr>>,
                                  And<GLTranDoc.tranModule, Equal<Constants.aR>>>>.Select(Base, pi.RefNbr);


                if (gltd != null)
                {

                    var piext = PXCache<PaymentInfo>.GetExtension<PaymentInfoExt>(pi);
                    if (piext != null)
                    {
                        piext.UsrBatchNbr = gltd.BatchNbr;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: I'm not seeing the actual code that use the filter value so the error could be there. Also make sure you debug the value where it's used. You can use traces or other mechanisms but you should debug that filter value at the time it is used to make sure it's not null in that context.

Comment: There's also lots of conditions in your code so unless you properly debug it it's possible that the field is simply not initialized as you believe it is. Having a FieldSelecting event that only returns a constant like e.ReturnValue = "Test"; would eliminate the possibility that the conditions prevented initialization.

Comment: Thanks Hugues - I did get an answer from Acumatica support.  I'll post it  here.